# Do I have to return a list if I append to it inside a function?

Tags: python, list, function, return, append

Consider a function in Python that gets as one of its arguments a list and inside it we append something to it. For instance:

```py
def add_new_number_squared(new_number, numbers_list):
    numbers_list.append(num**2)

my_list = [0]
add_new_number_squared(2, my_list)
```

Now `my_list[1]` will contain the value `4`, but is it a good practice or should I `return` `numbers_list` inside `add_new_number_squared` instead? To be more clear, should I write:

```py
def add_new_number_squared(new_number, numbers_list):
    numbers_list.append(new_number**2)
    return numbers_list

my_list = [0]
my_list = add_new_number_squared(2, my_list)
```

instead of the code above?

Comment: It's quite subjective, but my instinct would be to call out as strongly as possible that this function mutates its argument - so don't return, and add a mention in the docstring. My reasoning is that if you also return then it's easier to think that the function doesn't mutate and that reassigning its return value is necessary - and overlooking this kind of mutation is a source of bugs